# Facebook SDK iOS - "Update your browser"

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-login

I am trying to enable "Login with Facebook" in one of our apps, like this:

```
    [FBAppCall handleDidBecomeActive];

    if ((FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateOpen) || (FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateOpenTokenExtended))
    {
        [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
        return;
    }

    [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"email"] allowLoginUI:YES completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {
    }];
```

When I am logged in to Facebook on the iOS device (through Settings), I see a popup asking me if I want to allow access - I can accept it and everything is fine.

However, when I am not logged in, I will just see a browser "popup" telling me that my browser is not supported. I am using a custom button, from where I then call the code above. This code is taken directly from the [tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/v2.2). How can I get this to work? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem: The value in "URL Schemes" had a typo...